# custom listbox control event handling

Tags: wpf, event-handling, listbox

I'm following MVVM pattern. I have created custom listbox control naming it as ExtendedListbox.

in xmal, I have define listbox and define ItemSource property.

`<ExtendedListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">`

in my viewmodel, I have defined students as ObservableCollection.

public ObservableCollection `<Student>` Students;

Runtime, I'm adding/removing student object in Students collection.

In my ExtendedListBox control class, i want to know which object get added/removed from datasource of listbox.

is there any event that get triggered when any item get added or removed from datasource of listbox?

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as answered (checkmark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an `MVVM` style then I would suggest using `System.Windows.Interactivity` and use `Behaviors.

Sample usage.

**Behavior class**

```
public class ListBoxBehavior : Behavior<ListBox>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AddedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AddedItems", typeof (List<object>), typeof (ListBoxBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(new List<object>()));

    public List<object> AddedItems
    {
        get { return (List<object>) GetValue(AddedItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AddedItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RemovedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("RemovedItems", typeof(List<object>), typeof(ListBoxBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(new List<object>));

    public List<object> RemovedItems
    {
        get { return (List<object>) GetValue(RemovedItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RemovedItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        var observableCollection = AssociatedObject.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<object>;
        if (observableCollection != null)
        {
            observableCollection.CollectionChanged += ItemsSourceOnCollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        var observableCollection = AssociatedObject.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<object>;
        if (observableCollection != null)
        {
            observableCollection.CollectionChanged -= ItemsSourceOnCollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private void ItemsSourceOnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
    {
        AddedItems.Clear();
        RemovedItems.Clear();
        switch (notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                foreach (var newItem in notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.NewItems)
                {
                    AddedItems.Add(newItem);
                }
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                foreach (var newItem in notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.NewItems)
                {
                    RemovedItems.Add(newItem);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
    <ListBox>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ListBoxBehavior AddedItems="{Binding AddedItems}"/>
            <ListBoxBehavior AddedItems="{Binding RemovedItems}"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </ListBox>
```

What happens is that the events that are subscribed is encapsulated in the behavior class and you can now create a binding to the dependency property that is associated with the class which is the `ListBox`.

Comment: Thanks, will try out this solution, what i want to achieve is, ExtendedListBox will draw a multiple student object (i.e rectangles object) side by side. so if we add new student object, ExtendedListBox will finds newly added rectangle position by calculating last rectangle position and accordingly draw a rectangle. when we remove student object from ObservableCollection, ExtendedListBox will re-arrange the position of other rectangles accordingly. in viewModel i don't want to set position of rectangles, position finding and re-arranging the rectangles should be taken care by extended class.

Comment: The given example should work and a little bit of coding for the business logic that you need. :)

Comment: I have another query, In ExtendedListBox constructor, i have defined                                                                    this.MouseMove += ExtendedListBox_MouseMove; this.MouseLeftButtonDown += ExtendedListBox_MouseLeftButtonDown; this.MouseLeftButtonUp += ExtendedListBox_MouseLeftButtonUp; when i click on item, i'm not getting MouseLeftButtonDown event but getting MouseLeftButtonUp event when we release the mouse. instead of MouseLeftButtonDown(), I'm getting OnSelectionChanged() event, is there any other way to trap the MouseLeftButtonDown event? event needed for drag and drop

Comment: When you release the mouse that's mouse up. When you don't release that's mouse button down.